# Can I get INSTAGRAM media more than 20 from the '/users/self/media/recent' endpoint?

Tags: api, instagram, instagram-api

There is [the '/users/self/media/recent' endpoint](https://www.instagram.com/developer/endpoints/users/) on Instagram. It seems that we can get our past media using the query string such as `MAX_ID`, `MIN_ID` and `COUNT`. However, the endpoint always returns only the last page in which the number of the posts is 20.

There is a way to get more than 20 of our own posts?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because you are in "sandbox" mode. If you want to go "live mode" then you need to get approval from Instagram.
Refer this link.
https://www.instagram.com/developer/review/

Comment: It’s too simlpe. I don’t know why I can’t find it.